# Конвертация массива string в массив int C# одной строкой кода

Tags: c#

Как можно конвертировать строку чисел, разделённых пробелом, в массив int одной строкой кода?

Поделил на строки, но как конвертировать это в массив int, не создавая дополнительного массива string, не знаю.

```
int [] Mas = textBox1.Text.Split(' ')
```

Comment: а одной строкой кода это принципиальное условие?

Comment: А зачем вам массив? Ужасно неудобная структура данных.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Попробуйте следующее

```
int[] a = textBox1.Text.Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Правильнее будет написать

```
int[] a = textBox1.Text.Split(' ').
          Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( x )).
          Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Ответ ниже без лишнего Where интереснее http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451169/177411

Comment: А ещё все это можно завернуть в метод расширение, и тогда кода писать будет ещё меньше.

Comment: @ad1Dima: Ну, так любую функцию можно завернуть в расширение. `var result = source.ExtensionConverSourceToResult();`

Answer (score 7):

Раз уж пошел такой codegolf...

короткий вариант без LINQ, если не нужно вырезать пробелы:

```
Array.ConvertAll(text.Split(),int.Parse);
```

чуть более длинный вариант для случая, когда нужно вырезать пробелы:

```
Array.ConvertAll(Regex.Split(text,@"\s+"),int.Parse);
```

Минимальные варианты через LINQ без/c `RemoveEmptyEntries`

```
text.Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
text.Split(new[]{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1, но чё-то я не уверен, что с регуляркой лучше (быстрее, читабельнее), чем с LINQ.

Comment: @VladD регулярка заменяет не Linq, а `Split(new[]{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`. могу добавить вариант без вырезания пробелов и без регулярки :)

Comment: И правда! Не стоит мне делать категорические высказывания после 11 вечера :)

Comment: Кстати, не знал о `Array.ConvertAll`. (Но второго плюса у меня нет.)

Comment: @VladD я тоже не знал, [выгуглил на enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3533663/1988244) пол часа назад ))

Comment: Вот и хорошо, все левелапнулись немножко :) Поставил плюс тому ответу.

Answer (score 5):

```
int[] result = textBox1.Text.Split( new[]{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int[] a = textBox1.Text.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```